# How to display a form with multiple effects as a modal using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form and a button. I want to show the form as a modal on click of that button and the modal should have a particular effect such as fadeIN, slide, etc using jquery. Is there any plugin that can help me out on this?

Something like:

[image]

Comment: Did you try jQuery UI plugin ?

Comment: maybe JQuery itself ?

Comment: which jquery plugin should i use? i tried blockUI but didn't like the effect.

Comment: try to do this with "bootstrap" search on google

Comment: Jquery comes with its own plugin JQueryUI. JQueryUI provide some widgets like, dialogs http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

Comment: Please see the editing in the question. I want something like this. Any help?